# Using std::vector in Java with SWIG

Tags: java, c++, vector, swig, pjsip

I'm new to this SWIG thing and the interaction between Java and C++.
I'm trying using pjsip library wrapped with Java.

i have the following structure in a file called "call.hpp":

```
/**
 * This structure contains parameters for Call::onCreateMediaTransportSrtp()
 * callback.
 */
struct OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam
{
    /**
     * The media index in the SDP for which the SRTP media transport
     * will be used.
     */
    unsigned                mediaIdx;

    /**
     * Specify whether secure media transport should be used. Application
     * can modify this only for initial INVITE.
     * Valid values are PJMEDIA_SRTP_DISABLED, PJMEDIA_SRTP_OPTIONAL, and
     * PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY.
     */
    pjmedia_srtp_use        srtpUse;

    /**
     * Application can modify this to specify the cryptos and keys
     * which are going to be used.
     */
    vector<SrtpCrypto>      cryptos;
};
```

now, this how the Java wrapper for this function looks like(i've omitted some getters and setters to reduce length):

```
package org.pjsip.pjsua2;

public class OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam {
  private transient long swigCPtr;
  protected transient boolean swigCMemOwn;

  protected OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        pjsua2JNI.delete_OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public void setCryptos(SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj__SrtpCrypto_t value) {
    pjsua2JNI.OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam_cryptos_set(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj__SrtpCrypto_t.getCPtr(value));
  }

  public SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj__SrtpCrypto_t getCryptos() {
    long cPtr = pjsua2JNI.OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam_cryptos_get(swigCPtr, this);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj__SrtpCrypto_t(cPtr, false);
  }

  public OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam() {
    this(pjsua2JNI.new_OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam(), true);
  }

}
```

now, i don't know how to use setCryptos with the SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj__SrtpCrypto_t type in the parameter.
i've trying the following:

```
SrtpCrypto crypto = new SrtpCrypto();
crypto.setName("AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80");
OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam prm = new OnCreateMediaTransportSrtpParam();
Vector<SrtpCrypto> cryptos = new Vector<SrtpCrypto>();
cryptos.add(crypto);
prm.setCryptos(cryptos);
```

but i get the following error:

```
error: incompatible types: Vector<SrtpCrypto> cannot be converted to SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj_SrtpCrypto_t
```

any ideas on how to proceed?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: SWIGTYPE_p_ is an opaque type, you can't do anything with it. You need to use a typemap to map a vector to say an ArrayList. Have a look at the built-in SWIG std_vector.i

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm still struggling to understand where to start from..

Comment: What do you currently have in your .i file that makes the `Vector` type? What version of SWIG are you using?

Comment: you are passing invalid type argument to setCryptos method. you are passing SrtpCrypto type instead of  SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj__SrtpCrypto_t type argument. check with it.

Comment: @Flexo the pjsip library was built with SWIG 3.0.7, I do se the following line: "%template(SrtpCryptoVector)  std::vector<pj::SrtpCrypto>;" but no file called SrtpCryptoVector.java is created.. i didn't compile the library myself, maybe i should try to do so?

Comment: @NandhaKumar but the setCryptos method requires kind of a vector and i'm not able to pass type SWIGTYPE_p_vectorT_pj__SrtpCrypto_t as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown there's a mismatch between the types SWIG sees and the types being used.

In call.hpp you have:

```
vector<SrtpCrypto>
```

This vector here is almost certainly one from namespace std, which you've told SWIG to wrap, but here because of namespace directives of some sort that you've not shown it the question SWIG hasn't realised they're the same type, and used a default opaque type instead which isn't interchangable.

The simplest fix is for you to change your header file to say:

```
std::vector<SrtpCrypto>
```

instead then the error will almost certainly go away.